# Redirect 1page on wordpress to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, subdomain

I need to redirect one page of the website (created in WordPress) to a subdomain.

EXAMPLE: `www.example.com/one-page/` to => `one-page.example.com`

Ideas? I'm the newbie.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding following to `.htaccess`

```
Redirect 301 www.example.com/one-page/ http://one-page.example.com
```